# Search if elements from list are contained at least once in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list of strings

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['aa','b','d']
```

I need to check if every element from list a is included in any element in list b

I tried couple of solutions, but below one I thought should work, but it always returning True

```
def list_compare(list1,list2):

for item in list1:
    if any(item for s in list2):
        return True
return False

print(list_compare(a,b))
```

Anyone has any idea ?

I need that comparison for searching keywords in query files. I'm searching if all keywords are in file (file is split into lines as list) and if yes then return all lines containing any of the keyword.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the desired output?

Comment: "included in any element in list b", do you mean that 'a' in list a can be match with 'aa' in list b?

Comment: Yes, 'a' in list a should be match with 'aa' and it should go to next element from list a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` and `all` like this

```
>>> def list_compare(list1,list2):
...     return all(any(x in y for y in list2) for x in list1)
... 
>>> print(list_compare(a,b))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(list1,list2):
    for item in list1:
        if item in list2:  #checking the item is present in list2
            continue       # if yes, goes for next item in list1 to check
        else:
            return False   #if no, immediately comes out with "False"
    else:
        return True        #reaches here, only if all the items in list1 is 
                           #present in list2 , returning "True"

    print(compare(lista,listb))
```

Comment: Although your post might answer the question it lacks some explaining text and documentation. Please edit your answer and provide some.

Answer (score 0):

Finds words usage in lines. **Word can be a substring of line** (line can contain multiple words).

```
wordsToFind = ['a','b','c']
linesOfDocument = ['aa','ab','1234b','d']
for word in wordsToFind:
    for line in linesOfDocument:
        if word in line:
            print('Found word ' + word + ' in line ' + line)
```

Output of example:

```
Found word a in line aa
Found word a in line ab
Found word b in line ab
Found word b in line 1234b
```